# React-select with value "undefined"

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-select

I'm using React-hook-form and I've created a 'FormSelect' component based on 'react-select'. When I use this field on the form to create a new record it saves the data normally. Now, when I select a record to edit, and it fills in all the form fields, including the fields that use 'FormSelect', the 'value' prop of those fields is "undefined".

**This is my FormSelect component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useController, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import HelpOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HelpOutline';
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";

import { hintForm } from "../../../utils/message";

export const FormSelect = ({ name, label, errors, options, control, message, defaultValue}) => {
  const { field: { value, onChange, ...rest } } = useController({ name: name, control });
  
  const toggleHint = (label, msg) => {
    hintForm('info',msg, label, 'dark')
  }  

  return (
    <>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label 
          className={`label-input-form ${errors[name] ? 'validation-form' : ''}`}
        >
          {label}
          <span className="field-required">*</span>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="help"
            onClick={() => toggleHint(label, message)}
          >
            <HelpOutlineIcon
              sx={{
                fontSize: '.8rem'
              }}
            />
          </IconButton>
        </label>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name={name}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <Select   
              {...field}
              className="react-select-container"
              placeholder="selecione ou digite"
              isClearable
              options={options}
              onChange={option => onChange(option ? option.value : option)}
              defaultValue={defaultValue ? options.find(x => x.value === defaultValue) : defaultValue}  
              value={value ? options.find(x => x.value === value) : value}
            />
  
          )}
        />

      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

**And this is the main component:**

```
<div className='col-md-12 col-lg-6 mb-3'\>
    <FormSelect  
        label={casetype.label} 
        name={casetype.name} 
        errors={errors} 
        message={HELP_HINTS\[casetype.name\]}                 
        control={control}
        options={tipoServico}
        defaultValue={useCase?.casetype}
    />
</div>
```